# Set javascript variable to the value of a button with different text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button thats value is set based on a mysql query in php like so:

```
echo "<td><button class='jsontable' onclick='Copythat(this.value)' value='" . $row['json'] . "'> " . $row['name'] . "</button></td>";
```

the text of the button is the name row, which works currently.

and a function that i have basically in place to try and grab the string and send it to the load function. the load function needs to receive only text of that mysql row json

```
function Copythat(el.val) {
var jsontoload = $(el.val).html();
load(jsontoload);
 }
```

Comment: Cool.  So what exactly is your question?

Comment: function parameters must be variables, not object properties. Remove the `el.`.

Comment: `function Copythat(el.val) {` would need to be something simply like `function Copythat(val) {` . You're sending a single value to the function. it no longer has the context of the object from which it came. If you need to pass the whole element, then do `onclick='Copythat(this)'`

Comment: @ADyson this grabs the text of the button, but i need the value

Comment: `.attr("value")` should help. Maybe even `.val()` although not sure you can use that on a button element or not. Try it. And you could have googled how to get element attribute values using jQuery quite easily. Did you do any research?

Comment: @ADyson been googling and trying everything you suggested all day. you cant get the element attributes if you don't have an ID to work with, that is the exact issue im running into here, thanks anyway

Comment: Er, but you've got the element to work with, if you pass `this` into your function, as I suggested. You've already got the element as an object, its ID is not required. My previous comment was about how to get the value instead of the text, which is what you'd asked just now, and that's nothing to do with IDs. .html() would get you the inner HTML of the button, which will contain the text, whereas the .attr() can get you the value of a specific attribute. You seem to be conflating two things with your comments.

Comment: Anyway I've written an answer to try and clarify your options for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `this` to your function, you get the context of the element where the event occurred. Once you've got that, you can pass it to jQuery and you can get the "value" attribute using the `.val()` shortcut method.

Note that `function Copythat(el.val) {` needs to be something simply like `function Copythat(val) {` - function parameters must be standalone variables, they cannot be written like object properties.

```js
function Copythat(input) {
  var attrValue = $(input).val();
  alert(attrValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='jsontable' onclick='Copythat(this)' value='Something'>A button</button>
```

You could also convert the whole thing to jQuery and ditch the inline event handler:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".jsontable").click(function(event) {
    var attrValue = $(this).val();
    alert(attrValue);    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='jsontable' value='Something'>A button</button>
```

Or it should also be noted that for something as simple as this you don't really need jQuery at all:

```js
function Copythat(input) {
  alert(input.value);
}
```

```html
<button class='jsontable' onclick='Copythat(this)' value='Something'>A button</button>
```

Another further simplification if you literally only need the value to go into your function:

```js
function Copythat(input) {
  alert(input);
}
```

```html
<button class='jsontable' onclick='Copythat(this.value)' value='Something'>A button</button>
```

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what anyone thought was wrong with this answer to cause a downvote, but ok.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, sorry i am really just trying to modyify the existing code from a web developer that left a project unfinished, all i know is HTML and trying to make sense of it. the jQuery free version worked perfectly!